# Correct action for question posted by trolling OP

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

This question was removed by the author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354336/c-programming-language-arrays-long-and-interesting

The question in itself seems like an innocent homework problem. A couple of run of the mill comments were posted before the author started posting extremely offensive comments. I managed to flag four of them. It still managed to generate a lengthy conversation between the author and two other users before the author removed it.

I had asked if anyone else considered voting to close the question, but my comment was ignored.

What should I have chosen for the reason to flag it? Also, what will happen to the author now that the 'evidence' has been deleted?

Comment: For reference - Moderators can still see all deleted comments, so the evidence doesn't really get removed.

Comment: Seems the OP wasn't the only one throwing the insults around

Comment: This never ends well.  Flag the question, not the comments.

Comment: Yeah. Initially flag an isolated comment, but if it gets out of hand, flag using the "other" option and explain the situation. And then walk away. Don't engage, don't talk back...

Comment: I highly recommend spanking as a punishment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I have chosen for the reason to flag it?

Well for that particular question I would have voted to close it as "unclear what you're asking". Although there is some minor mention of some sorting requirement in the code snippet, but it's not definitive.

The question shows some code, so we can't just assume they haven't tried anything, and as it is clearly about programming then we can eliminate any of the "off topic" questions.

"too broad" and "primarily opinion based" are also not valid options for us because the question isn't clear enough as to be able identify what the OP actually want, therefore we don't know if they are asking for too much, or asking for opinions.

Other than closing, the question itself provides nothing offensive, so there would be no sense in resorting to any of the flagging options (doesn't belong, spam, moderator attention).

To sum up, my action would have been a **downvote** and an "**unclear what you're asking**" close vote. And maybe I would have left a comment if there were not already any.

Comment: I think he meant *flags*, not *closevotes*.

Comment: @Doorknob: to which the answer is no flags. But he is a low-rep user, his close votes are done via flags anyway (or so I recall)

Comment: Meh, I personally would have flagged as "other" and explained the rude comments.

Comment: @Doorknob: I was answering based on flagging the question, and not considering the comments. I think remyabel's question here seems to be asking how to deal with the question, rather than the comments